# Assign multiple o365 licenses to a single user using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm using a simple Powershell script to add new users to O365 and assign a license. However im trying to add multiple licenses at once to a single user.

**Powershell**

```
Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Powershell\NewAccounts.csv" | foreach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -UsageLocation $_.UsageLocation -LicenseAssignment $_.AccountSkuId} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Powershell\NewAccountResults.csv" -Verbose
```

**.CSV**

```
DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,UserPrincipalName,Usagelocation,AccountSkuId
Test Jesse,Tes,Jesse,test.jesse@(tenant).nl,NL,(tenant):EMS
```

---

For this example i'd like to add the EMS & ENTERPRISEPACK license to the test user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another filed to your CSV:

```
DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,UserPrincipalName,Usagelocation,AccountSkuIdEMS, AccountSkuIdENTERPRISEPACK
Test Jesse,Tes,Jesse,test.jesse@(tenant).nl,NL,(tenant):EMS,(tenant):ENTERPRISEPACK
```

And tweak the script:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Powershell\NewAccounts.csv" | foreach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -UsageLocation $_.UsageLocation -LicenseAssignment $_.AccountSkuIdEMS,$_.AccountSkuIdENTERPRISEPACK} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Powershell\NewAccountResults.csv" -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple script to add multiple licenses. Only information needed is the UPN, which in my environment is the mail address.

```
Connect-MsolService
Import-Csv 'C:\usersmailaddress.CSV' | foreach {Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.EmailAdress -UsageLocation BR
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.EmailAdress -AddLicenses mydomain:ENTERPRISEPACK
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.EmailAdress -AddLicenses mydomain:EMS
}
```

You can adapt it to your needs.